# Is the converse of Dirichlet convergence test true?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Dirichlet convergence test for series says:

Condition 1: Let $\{ a_n \}$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence of real numbers

Condition 2: Let $\{ b_n \}$ is a sequence of real numbers such that for all $N,$ $ \sum_{n=1}^N b_n < M $ where is $ M $ is a constant (not dependent on $N$

Example: $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \sin n $ is convergent.

If conditions 1 and 2 are true, then $ S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n b_n $ is convergent.

My question is: is the converse also true? That is, if $ S $ is convergent and condition 1 is true, then does it imply condition 2 is also true? Or if $S$ is convergent and condition 2 is true then does condition 1 follow?

Comment: In proper MathJax usage the $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ belong inside the math tags, thus $\{ a_n\},$ as in my edits to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, to both.

For the first:  take $$a_n=\frac 1{n^3}\quad b_n=n$$  then $\sum a_nb_n$ converges, condition $1$ is met, but condition $2$ fails.

For the second: swap $a_n, b_n$ in the above.

Comment: { $ b_n $ } doesn’t satisfy condition 1 or condition 2. It is not decreasing nor is the partial sum bounded for all N.

Comment: Yes, that is my point.  With my first choice, $a_n$ satisfies $1$ and $\sum a_nb_n$ converges but $b_n$ does not satisfy $2$.  Swapping the two, we now have $\sum a_nb_n$ converges, the new $b_n=\frac 1{n^3}$ has bounded partial sums so $2$ is satisfied but the new $a_n=n$ fails $1$.

Comment: You’re right. I think I was confused.